# List of databases used for a sharepoint 2010 farm?

Tags: powershell, administration, database, content-database

How to find the list of databases are used by a SharePoint 2010 Farm, including content databases, service application databases and configuration database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know databases in your farm instance, use Get-SPDatabase as suggested by another answer.

If you want to understand what databases sharepoint creates and what exactly sharepoint stores in them, check [Databases That Support SharePoint 2010 Products](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=187969)

Comment: Get-SPDatabase | Export-Csv c:\sharepointDbs.csv

Answer (score 8):

Try SharePoint PowerShell:  Get-SPDatabase

http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-40-powershell-get-spdatabase.html

Answer (score 8):

Why not simply using Central Admin... :-)
(works even if you do NOT have access to either the physical server (console) or databases server.

Central Admin -> Upgrade and Migration -> Review Database Status.
By pasting /_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx at your CA url.

Rgds, Arjan Vos

Answer (score 1):

You can this resource. It's very clear from size, name, attribute to capability of backup/restore by other tools.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx