# How can I determine whether a content database is being used?

Tags: 2007, content-database

I noticed quite a few SharePoint content databases with random names (i.e. WSS_Content_30cb56f0b9eb430a8a2e3180604efd7b). I believe these were created by developers during deployment, and were never removed. I realize this may be a question I should ask a DBA: How do I determine whether these databases are being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to know what DB is used for a site collection you can go to the central administration, open aplication managment, then click on view all site collections. Select a site collection that you wish to check. There is information what DB is used for this site collection.

The reason why I told about site collection is site collection is the smallest piece that can store in the separated DB.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know which particular farm these databases could have been created from. We have at least three different SharePoint applications in multiple environments. That would be at least nine instances of SharePoint 3.0 Central Admin I need to go to. Is there a way of just checking whether the database has been connected to in the last month?

Comment: May be [this thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16052/list-of-databases-used-for-a-sharepoint-2010-farm) will be helpful.